# namespace collision in C++, stuck in finding a solution

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to combine two libraries in my code using XML.
After reading many post here, I decided to wrap the smaller library in a namespace enviroment.

Now here starts my problem. (I'will use pseudo code, because there are ~2000 lines of code)

xmlParser.h

```
#include<...>
namespace xmlparser
{

stuff that belongs to headerfile

}
```

xmlParser.cpp

```
#include "xmlParser.h"
#include "..."
using namespace xmlparser;

stuff that belongs to source code ...
```

Now I get an error in xmlParser.cpp on line 1000 (I assume until here everything went fine ???)

undefined reference to `xmlparser::stringDup(char const*, int)'

line that raises the error:

```
XMLNode XMLNode::createXMLTopNode(XMLCSTR lpszName, char isDeclaration) {  return XMLNode(NULL,stringDup(lpszName),isDeclaration); }
```

in the header file:

```
XMLDLLENTRY XMLSTR stringDup(XMLCSTR source, int cbData=-1);
```

in the source:

```
// Duplicate a given string.
XMLSTR stringDup(XMLCSTR lpszData, int cbData)
{
if (lpszData==NULL) return NULL;

XMLSTR lpszNew;
if (cbData==-1) cbData=(int)xstrlen(lpszData);
lpszNew = (XMLSTR)malloc((cbData+1) * sizeof(XMLCHAR));
if (lpszNew)
{
    memcpy(lpszNew, lpszData, (cbData) * sizeof(XMLCHAR));
    lpszNew[cbData] = (XMLCHAR)NULL;
}
return lpszNew;
}
```

More undefined reference to `xmlparser::stringDup(char const*, int)' are given.
Did I made a systematic error?

Comment: So you declare the function in the namespace but define it outside?

Comment: Get rid of the using directive. Open and close your namespace, and define those function inside that scope.

Comment: How can I define the function in the namespace? Wrap the code in a namepace {} enviroment, too?

Comment: Yes! The using directive is a lazy and error prone shortcut to that.

Comment: Thank You now it works. I thought I can use the namespace {} enviroment once only and have to use using namespace; afterwards

Comment: An alternative is to specify the `namespace` when defining the function, like you would to for a function in class scope: `XMLSTR xmlparser::stringDup(XMLCSTR lpszData, int cbData)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to put the contents of xmlParser.cpp into the namespace scope "namespace xmlparser{ xxxxxx }" ?

the contents of xmlParser.cpp also need to be put in name space scope of namespace like blow:

```
   #include "xmlParser.h"
    #include "..."
    namespace xmlparser
    {
        *** the contents of xmlParser.cpp ***
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sources you have to change

```
XMLSTR stringDup(XMLCSTR lpszData, int cbData)
```

to

```
XMLSTR xmlparser::stringDup(XMLCSTR lpszData, int cbData)
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct answer but I have to change to many lines that way. I will use the     namespace xmlparser
    {
        *** the contents of xmlParser.cpp ***
    } solution.